# How to insert "," in text [php]

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to insert "," in text 
I received the text as follows :

```
A1780G1100001 A1780G1100002 A1780G1100003
```

When I show the text, i want to show like this :

```
A1780G1100001,A1780G1100002,A1780G1100003,
```

What are the methods and code ?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?  Is there a pattern to where you want to add the `,`'s

Comment: I tried writing code to count characters. When count 13 characters will add "," . But i don't know how to write.I started practicing programming for 2 months.

Comment: It could be worth trying to find some tutorials which will help in learning some of the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> JS

Use [Replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) function.

```js
let str='A1780G1100001 A1780G1100002 A1780G1100003';
str = str.replace(/\s+/g, ',');
console.log(str); // "A1780G1100001,A1780G1100002,A1780G1100003"
```

> PHP

Use [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) OR [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace)

```
$str = 'A1780G1100001 A1780G1100002 A1780G1100003';
$res = str_replace(' ', ',', $str);
echo $res; // "A1780G1100001,A1780G1100002,A1780G1100003"
echo "\n";
$res = preg_replace('/\s+/', ',', $str);
echo $res; // "A1780G1100001,A1780G1100002,A1780G1100003"
```

Comment: Please do not reward low-quality questions that show absolutely no research effort with an answer.

Comment: @Andreas. I'll keep that in mind from now on.